# Multiple CGContextRef in drawRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

In overriding a UIView drawRect, I draw the main image with `CGContextDrawImage`. Over it I need to draw another image (with a multiply blend mode), so I actually need to draw *over* it.

This second image needs to be prepares since it's generated dynamically (it has to be masked, may be different size and so), so in the end I need to generate it. How can I get a second context where I can draw and mask this second image **before** applying it over the main one with? If I draw on the current context, it gets directly drawn no the main one before I can mask it.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionBg.png"].CGImage);

    // prevent the drawings to be flipped
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    // generate the overlay
    if ([self isActive] == NO && self.fullDelay != 0) { // TODO: remove fullDelay check!
        int segmentSize = (ACTION_SIZE / [self fullDelay]);

        for (int i=0; i<[self fullDelay]; i++) {
            float alpha = 0.9 - (([self fullDelay] * 0.1) - (i * 0.1));
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:14.0/255.0 alpha:alpha] setFill];

            if (currentDelay > i) {
                CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, i * segmentSize, ACTION_SIZE, segmentSize);
                CGContextFillRect(ctx, r);
            }
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.3] setFill];
            CGRect line = CGRectMake(0, (i * segmentSize) + segmentSize - 1 , ACTION_SIZE, 1);
            CGContextFillRect(ctx, line);
        }

        UIImage *overlay = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIImage *overlayMasked = [TDUtilities maskImage:overlay withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"actionMask.png"]];
    }
}
```

Here overlayMasked now contains the correct image, but since I've prepared it using the main context, its is not all messed. Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bitmap context using either [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW8) or [`CGBitmapContextCreate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE).  After you're finished drawing in the bitmap context, you can get an image using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` or `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` (as appropriate), and then release the context using either `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` or `CGContextRelease`.